# Sort in column 'Total' not working angular mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, ecmascript-6, reduce

My mat table is working fine, all my columns are sorting, except my last column that calculate the sum values from the other columns using reduce.

Im kinda stuck in this issue, first though that it could be due the reduce method happens after the `OnInit` lifecycle, but even if I declare `this.dataSource.data = this.data` in `ngAfterViewInit` doesnt work.

My HTML template:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'hidden': !hasData()}">
  <div class="subcollection-name">{{subCollection.name}}</div>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table
      matSort
      mat-table
      class="items-table"
      [dataSource]="dataSource"
    >
      <ng-container matColumnDef="coverUrl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
          <img class="item-image" src="{{item.displayImage}}" onError="this.src='assets/images/no-image-available.png';">
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>
          {{ "collectionReportsSubcollectionTablesTotalRow" | translate }}
        <td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          {{ 'collectionRejectionReportRejectedItemTableHeaderId' | translate}}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
          <a target="_blank" routerLink="/item/{{item.id}}" class="item-id-link">ID-{{ item.id }}</a>
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          {{ 'collectionRejectionReportRejectedItemTableHeaderName' | translate}}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item | displayItemName }}</td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngFor="let step of stepsName$ | async">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{step}}">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            {{step}}
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ 'stepsReportAverageTimeSpentDaysUnit' | translate: { numberDays: getDataOfItemForStepName(item.id, step) } }}</td>
          <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{ 'stepsReportAverageTimeSpentDaysUnit' | translate: { numberDays: getTotalDataOfStep(step) } }}</td>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="total" stickyEnd>
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          {{ "collectionReportsSubcollectionTablesTotalCollumn" | translate }}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ 'stepsReportAverageTimeSpentDaysUnit' | translate:{ numberDays: getTotalDataOfItem(item.id) } }}</td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{ 'stepsReportAverageTimeSpentDaysUnit' | translate:{ numberDays: getTotalDataOfAll() } }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>
      <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="columns"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

TypeScript file

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { SubCollection } from 'model/item-tree/collection';
import { MatSort, MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { Component, ViewChild, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, AfterViewInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-collection-steps-report-subcollection-table',
  templateUrl: './collection-steps-report-subcollection-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./collection-steps-report-subcollection-table.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CollectionStepsReportSubcollectionTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  @Input() data: any[];
  @Input() subCollection: SubCollection;
  @Input() filterBy$: Observable<string>;
  @Input() stepsName$: BehaviorSubject<string[]>;

  public columns: string[];
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string): boolean => {
      if (filter === 'id') {
        return true;
      }
      const id = data['id'] as string;
      const name = data['name'] as string;
      const matchId = (id) ? id.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 : true;
      const matchName = (name) ? name.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 : true;
      return matchName || matchId;
    };
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.filterBy$.subscribe(
      filter => {
        this.dataSource.filter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();

        if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
          this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
        }
      }
    );

    this.stepsName$.subscribe(
      sn => {
        this.columns = ['coverUrl', 'id', 'name', ...sn, 'total'];
      }
    );
    this.dataSource.data = this.data;
  }

  public hasData(): boolean {
    return Array.isArray(this.data) && this.data.length > 0;
  }

  public getTotalDataOfItem(itemId: string): number {
    const item = this.data.find(i => i.id === itemId);
    return this.stepsName$.getValue().reduce((acc, stepName) => {
      return acc += item[stepName];
    }, 0);
  }

  public getTotalDataOfAll(): number {
    return this.data.reduce(
      (acc1, item) => acc1 += this.stepsName$.getValue().reduce((acc2, stepName) => acc2 += item[stepName], 0)
    , 0);
  }

  public getDataOfItemForStepName(itemId: string, stepName: string): string {
    return this.data.find(i => i.id === itemId)[stepName];
  }

  public getTotalDataOfStep(step: string): number {
    return this.data.reduce((acc, item) => acc += item[step], 0);
  }
}
```

Glad to have any tip or help to clarify my mind to solve this issue :) Thx!

Comment: Have a look at the docs. custom sortingDataAccessor should be your bullet point https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, I found out that my issue was that the column 'total' wasnt been part of the 'item' object.

So I implementate a `map` method to my data, assigning the return of `getTotalDataOfItem` function to my new array of data inside `ngOnInit`, and it works fine!

Since my item now has the 'total' column, I had to refactor the HTML template to render the `item.total` in the `<td>` instead of the return of `getTotalDataOfItem(item.id)`

To make things work, just add this code inside `ngOnInit` in the TS file

```
const dataWithTotal = this.data.map(
  value => {
    return {
      ...value, total: this.getTotalDataOfItem(value['id'])
    };
  }
);
```

Then refactor the HTML file like this

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ 'stepsReportAverageTimeSpentDaysUnit' | translate:{ numberDays: item.total } }}</td>
```

Then enjoy your mat-table correctly sorting all the columns :)